# Domain issues of the Linux server which is cloned from other Linux box

Tags: linux, ssh, domain

We have cloned one of the Linux server from other server which is already part of domain. now we try to add the newly cloned Linux box to the domain, it was successful but we are unable to authenticate to this box.

whenever we try to login with domain ID to this box it is saying Access denied and also now other server is also started giving the similar issue. other server  means the one which we used as a cloning master. is there any way to resolve this issue because already Application team is installed the application on this server.

Comment: what does the logs in the domain controller  say?

Comment: AD team said, they didnt find anything. But when i execute klist -k, its showing hostnames of both problematic server and the server which is used for cloning.